# Linear equation solving program

Tags: php

I would like to program a solver for linear equations in PHP.
But here comes the problem. If the users types in f.e. 2a+4b=10, it should give me the array (2,4,10) but the same also when typing in f.e. 2x+4y=10 or 4y=10-2x. How can this be done in PHP? (also the variables should be ordered by alphabet).
Thanks for your suggestions!
Leon

Comment: This is a pretty simple thing to do, with a bit of research and trying, you'll be able to do it yourself. Check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/ ! (Also I won't give you the usual 'Stackoverflow isn't a homework solving community', but I guess you know that)

Comment: So you just want to strip the alpha characters?

Comment: How does your code look so far? Add it to the question!

Comment: Firstly, it is not a homework but for a math project. Secondly, it would be simple if the user really types in 2a+4b=10, then I could get the values via regular expressions. But if the user types in -10=-4b-2a, I have no idea how to form it into the version 2a+4b=10. To sum up, how is it possible to form any equation into the form ax+by=c. Thanks for your help!

Comment: and this is my solver so far: http://www.mathespass.at/gleichungssysteme_loeser.php